# Setting script-accessible cookie expiry based on wordpress_logged_in_# cookie

Tags: wordpress, cookies

I need a cookie to correctly display dynamic links for logged / anonymous users on cached pages. I thought that with default WordPress login cookie expiry being 14 days, I can't go wrong with creating my custom 14 days expiry script-accessible cookie and it should result in their expiry date synchronized:

```
add_action('wp_login', 'lal_login');
function lal_login() {
    $expiration = time() + 14*24*60*60;
    setcookie('wp_user_logged_in', 1, $expiration, '/');
    $_COOKIE['wp_user_logged_in'] = 1;
}

add_action('wp_logout', 'lal_logout');
function lal_logout() {
    unset($_COOKIE['wp_user_logged_in']);
    setcookie('wp_user_logged_in', null, -1, '/');
}
```

Unfortunately Chrome showed that expiry date of 2 default cookies and my custom cookie is not the same. Default cookies expire 12 hours later.

**wordpress_logged_in_#**

Created
Sunday, May 19, 2019 at 3:01:54 PM
Expires
Monday, June 3, 2019 at 3:01:54 AM

**wordpress_sec_#**

Created
Sunday, May 19, 2019 at 3:01:54 PM
Expires
Monday, June 3, 2019 at 3:01:54 AM

**wp_user_logged_in**

Created
Sunday, May 19, 2019 at 3:01:54 PM
Expires
Sunday, June 2, 2019 at 3:01:54 PM

I found that WordPress adds some 12 hour "grace period".

```
$expire = $expiration + ( 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
```

Should I simply make my cookie expire after 14 days 12 hours? I would also prefer expiration based on auth cookie, which can change based on filter, than hardcoded time. How can I achieve this? Line below shows how auth cookie expiration is calculated:

```
$expiration = time() + apply_filters( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 14 * DAY_IN_SECONDS, $user_id, $remember );
```

I see that WordPress also honors setting to not remember user, although I have problem understanding it, because code sets `$expire` to 0 in the next line. How could I support field to remember user unchecked correctly in my custom cookie, to mirror WordPress auth cookie?

Whole function responsible for setting auth cookie, located in pluggable.php, is the following:

```
function wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, $remember = false, $secure = '', $token = '' ) {
        if ( $remember ) {
            /**
             * Filters the duration of the authentication cookie expiration period.
             *
             * @since 2.8.0
             *
             * @param int  $length   Duration of the expiration period in seconds.
             * @param int  $user_id  User ID.
             * @param bool $remember Whether to remember the user login. Default false.
             */
            $expiration = time() + apply_filters( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 14 * DAY_IN_SECONDS, $user_id, $remember );

            /*
             * Ensure the browser will continue to send the cookie after the expiration time is reached.
             * Needed for the login grace period in wp_validate_auth_cookie().
             */
            $expire = $expiration + ( 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
        } else {
            /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/pluggable.php */
            $expiration = time() + apply_filters( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 2 * DAY_IN_SECONDS, $user_id, $remember );
            $expire     = 0;
        }

        if ( '' === $secure ) {
            $secure = is_ssl();
        }

        // Front-end cookie is secure when the auth cookie is secure and the site's home URL is forced HTTPS.
        $secure_logged_in_cookie = $secure && 'https' === parse_url( get_option( 'home' ), PHP_URL_SCHEME );

        /**
         * Filters whether the connection is secure.
         *
         * @since 3.1.0
         *
         * @param bool $secure  Whether the connection is secure.
         * @param int  $user_id User ID.
         */
        $secure = apply_filters( 'secure_auth_cookie', $secure, $user_id );

        /**
         * Filters whether to use a secure cookie when logged-in.
         *
         * @since 3.1.0
         *
         * @param bool $secure_logged_in_cookie Whether to use a secure cookie when logged-in.
         * @param int  $user_id                 User ID.
         * @param bool $secure                  Whether the connection is secure.
         */
        $secure_logged_in_cookie = apply_filters( 'secure_logged_in_cookie', $secure_logged_in_cookie, $user_id, $secure );

        if ( $secure ) {
            $auth_cookie_name = SECURE_AUTH_COOKIE;
            $scheme           = 'secure_auth';
        } else {
            $auth_cookie_name = AUTH_COOKIE;
            $scheme           = 'auth';
        }

        if ( '' === $token ) {
            $manager = WP_Session_Tokens::get_instance( $user_id );
            $token   = $manager->create( $expiration );
        }

        $auth_cookie      = wp_generate_auth_cookie( $user_id, $expiration, $scheme, $token );
        $logged_in_cookie = wp_generate_auth_cookie( $user_id, $expiration, 'logged_in', $token );

        /**
         * Fires immediately before the authentication cookie is set.
         *
         * @since 2.5.0
         * @since 4.9.0 The `$token` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param string $auth_cookie Authentication cookie value.
         * @param int    $expire      The time the login grace period expires as a UNIX timestamp.
         *                            Default is 12 hours past the cookie's expiration time.
         * @param int    $expiration  The time when the authentication cookie expires as a UNIX timestamp.
         *                            Default is 14 days from now.
         * @param int    $user_id     User ID.
         * @param string $scheme      Authentication scheme. Values include 'auth' or 'secure_auth'.
         * @param string $token       User's session token to use for this cookie.
         */
        do_action( 'set_auth_cookie', $auth_cookie, $expire, $expiration, $user_id, $scheme, $token );

        /**
         * Fires immediately before the logged-in authentication cookie is set.
         *
         * @since 2.6.0
         * @since 4.9.0 The `$token` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param string $logged_in_cookie The logged-in cookie value.
         * @param int    $expire           The time the login grace period expires as a UNIX timestamp.
         *                                 Default is 12 hours past the cookie's expiration time.
         * @param int    $expiration       The time when the logged-in authentication cookie expires as a UNIX timestamp.
         *                                 Default is 14 days from now.
         * @param int    $user_id          User ID.
         * @param string $scheme           Authentication scheme. Default 'logged_in'.
         * @param string $token            User's session token to use for this cookie.
         */
        do_action( 'set_logged_in_cookie', $logged_in_cookie, $expire, $expiration, $user_id, 'logged_in', $token );

        /**
         * Allows preventing auth cookies from actually being sent to the client.
         *
         * @since 4.7.4
         *
         * @param bool $send Whether to send auth cookies to the client.
         */
        if ( ! apply_filters( 'send_auth_cookies', true ) ) {
            return;
        }

        setcookie( $auth_cookie_name, $auth_cookie, $expire, PLUGINS_COOKIE_PATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, $secure, true );
        setcookie( $auth_cookie_name, $auth_cookie, $expire, ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, $secure, true );
        setcookie( LOGGED_IN_COOKIE, $logged_in_cookie, $expire, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, $secure_logged_in_cookie, true );
        if ( COOKIEPATH != SITECOOKIEPATH ) {
            setcookie( LOGGED_IN_COOKIE, $logged_in_cookie, $expire, SITECOOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, $secure_logged_in_cookie, true );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is mainly the cookie's expiration time, so:

> I see that WordPress also honors setting to not remember user,
>   although I have problem understanding it, because code sets `$expire`
>   to 0 in the next line.

When you call [`setcookie()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php), the 'expires' parameter should either be omitted or set to `0`, which either way means that the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes). So that's why WordPress needs to set it to 0 when the user didn't check the "Remember Me" checkbox upon logging in.

> How could I support field to remember user unchecked correctly in my
>   custom cookie, to mirror WordPress auth cookie?

Instead of "supporting it", you could use the `set_logged_in_cookie` hook to actually set your cookie. That way, you'd get the expected expiration time, regardless the user checked or not the "Remember Me" checkbox.

So the code:

1. Instead of this: `add_action('wp_login', 'lal_login');`

   Use: `add_action('set_logged_in_cookie', 'lal_login', 10, 2);`

   *Or this*: `add_action('set_auth_cookie', 'lal_login', 10, 2);`
2. And the `lal_login()`:

   ```php
   function lal_login( $cookie, $expire ) {
       // If the user didn't check the "Remember Me" checkbox, $expire would be 0.
       // So if you want, you can set $expire to 14 days, 2 days, etc.
       //$expire = $expire ? $expire : time() + 14 * DAY_IN_SECONDS;

       setcookie('wp_user_logged_in', 1, $expire, '/');
       $_COOKIE['wp_user_logged_in'] = 1;
   }
   ```

   Note: If you hook to `set_logged_in_cookie`, the `$cookie` would be the logged-in cookie value; if you hook to `set_auth_cookie`, the `$cookie` would be the authentication cookie value.

Comment: This works perfectly! I also realized that this 2 day value means that cookie will expire in 2 days if user without remember checked doesn't close browser session earlier.